# Hive timestamp query

Tags: sql, hadoop, casting, hive, timestamp

I created a hive table that has timestamp column (data type is timestamp) in the following format:

2017-01-23 21:23:17.261456

However when I do select like so. It does not work properly. It will select dates after the time stamp. Should the column be a string or I am using the query wrong?

```
select * from example where time_created < '2017-01-01 22:30:57.375117'
```

Comment: Timestamp literals don't work well with milliseconds, even worse with microseconds... Experiment with `'2017-01-01 22:30:57'` and `cast('2017-01-01 22:30:57' as TimeStamp)` and `cast('2017-01-01 22:30:57.375' as TimeStamp)` etc. etc. to zoom on the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem: the comparison among strings and timestamp was not automatically done.
This worked out for me:

```
select * from example 
         where unix_timestamp(time_created, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') < 
               unix_timestamp('2017-01-01 22:30:57.375117','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the data type of your filter like Time-Stamp to String comparison can be the issue. Try using from_utc_timestamp('2017-01-01 22:30:57.375117') or from_unix() commands.

Answer (score -1):

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2015-12-23 22:30:57.375' ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')) ;
```